# How set focus on specific input text field in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some `TextFormField` field in my flutter app. Here are the controllers of those fields.

```
TextEditingController nameCtrl = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController idCtrl = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController nodeCtrl = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController unitCodeCtrl = TextEditingController();
```

I want to set focus to the `unitCodeCtrl` text field programmatically when an event fired (on button click) but can not figure out how can I do that.

```
...,
onPressed:(){
  //what can i do for set focus to unitcode text field?
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First declare a focus node like this

```
final FocusNode unitCodeCtrlFocusNode = FocusNode();
```

then assign this focus node to that textfield

```
TextFormField(
     controller: unitCodeCtrl,
     focusNode: unitCodeCtrlFocusNode,
)
```

And on the button click call below method, this will set a focus

```
onPressed:(){
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(unitCodeCtrlFocusNode);
}
```

or

```
onPressed:(){
  unitCodeCtrlFocusNode.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `unitCodeCtrlFocusNode.requestFocus();` works for me.

Comment: Do it need dispose this FocusNode in dispose method?

Comment: For some reason, it didn't work for me. But I found you can set the focus to a TextFormField when it becomes visible by setting TextFormField(autofocus: true, ...). See: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/focus. This worked for me on the first try.